# Parsing xml special chars issue

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing, htmlspecialchars

I'm parsing an XML got from webservice using `SAX`.

One of the fields is a link, like the following

```
<link_site>
   http://www.ownhosting.com/webservice_332.asp?id_user=21395&amp;id_parent=33943
</link_site>
```

I have to get this link and save it, but it is saved like so: `id_parent=33943`.

Parser snippet:

```
//inside method startElement
else if(localName.equals("link_site")){
    this.in_link=true;
}
...
//inside method endElement
else if(localName.equals("link_site"){
     this.in_link=false;
}
```

Then, I get the content

```
else if(this.in_link){
    xmlparsing.setOrderLink(count, Html.fromHtml(new String(ch, start, length)).toString());
}//I get it and put in a HashMap<Integer,String>
```

I know that this issue is due to the special characters encoding.

What can I do?

Comment: have you try with **URLDecoder.decode(stingvalue, "UTF-8");**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

& makes parser to split the line and make several calls to characters() method. You need to concatinate the chunks. Something like this

```
    SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser()
            .parse(new File("1.xml"), new DefaultHandler() {
                String url;
                String element;

                @Override
                public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
                        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
                    element = qName;
                    url = "";
                }

                @Override
                public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
                    if (element.equals("link_site")) {
                        url += new String(ch, start, length); 
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
                        throws SAXException {
                    if (element.equals("link_site")) {
                        System.out.println(url.trim());
                        element = "";
                    }
                }
            });
```

prints

```
http://www.ownhosting.com/webservice_332.asp?id_user=21395&id_parent=33943
```

Comment: Ok, i tried your code and it works fine (for that, +1). But now, the url printed is `http://www.ownhosting.com/webservice_332.asp?id_user=id_parent=33943` ... Is it possible that the encoding tries to encode not only `&amp;` but `21395&amp;`?